# Multiple proxy_pass per 1 connection

Tags: nginx

In nginx I would like to have 1 location to proxy pass through multiple 
endpoints.
I'm trying to make my frontend talk to multiple services via websocket but to hold only 1 socket open against nginx.
Is that possible?

```
location /websockets {
  proxy_pass http://service-cluster-1/websocket;
  proxy_pass http://service-cluster-2/websocket;
  proxy_pass http://service-cluster-3/websocket;
}
```

Comment: Nope. What do you think should nginx do with answers from these servers?

Answer (score 1):

When NGINX proxies a request, it sends the request to a specified proxied server, fetches the response, and sends it back to the client.

So you cannot ask nginx to send request to multiple proxied servers at the same time